# !important overriden by a class of child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a very bad CSS rule (high specifity, use of !important) which sets color of text in a paragraph:

```
 #wrapper .article .text {
  color: green !important;
}
```

Then I put a simple span element in that paragraph and set color of the span text via simple class:

```
.black {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

How come, that this simple class with low specifity and no !important flag overrides the parent rule?

Full snippet on codepen.io here: http://codepen.io/Jarino/pen/oXYeQZ?editors=110

Comment: You missed to add the snippet

Comment: My apology, I edited the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply because there is no more specific rule for that `<span>` than what you have declared in `.black`. Even though it is a child element of the `<p>` that has an `important!` flagged rule, it only inherits the color from it if it can find no more specific other color definition. Inheritance from a parent context is the least specific "rule" possible. Also, the `!important` part of a rule is not inherited, afaik.

If this were not the case, you would be very commonly forced to either use `!important`whenever an element takes a style that it already inherited from the parent, or you would have to constantly use very long selectors to make sure your child element selector does not have a lower specificity than the definition it inherits.

Also, compare what Mozilla says on the subject:

> Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence
>   over inherited styles, regardless of the specificity of the inherited
>   rule.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#directly-targeted-elements

Comment: "Inheritance from a parent content is the least specific rule possible" - didn't know about that, but makes perfect sense, thank you for quick explanation :)

Comment: "Also, the !important part of a rule is not inherited, afaik." Correct, it's not inherited. The only thing it can do is affect which value is inherited by the child, if you have multiple rules targeting the same parent.

Answer (score 3):

The high-specificity rule applies only to the parent class. When it comes to it's children, the high-specificity of the parent class mellows down to a parent style that is inherited by the child.

And, when it comes to styling the child, all CSS rules specifically targeting it get precedence over the high-specificity rule of the parent.

If you do 'Inspect Element' for this child span tag in the Developer Console of your browser, you'll see how preference is given to CSS rules targeting that particular element that overrides all the parent styling that appears way down the list.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want your *.black* class to override the parent rule you can simply remove the color property from your *.black* class, the class mentioned in span will always have high specificity regardless of parent rule.

Answer (score 0):

Because `!important` applies only for current element style not for child elements with specified same property.

Answer (score 0):

> How come, that this simple class with low specifity and no !important
>   flag overrides the parent rule?

Well, because they are two different rules. 
You have your text class which is pretty strictly called but only a class without selector.

After you addded a span with a different class it will not be overwritten, because it's another rule. It gets applied to the span. And .text get applied to the paragraph.